# Create Certificate and verify embedded PublicKey

Tags: java, certificate

Hi I was wondering how you would verify that a PublicKey belongs to a certain individual or party during an RSA key exchange using a Certificate in java ? I need to know how to do this any help would be much appreciated and if you could provide a code example that would be awesome, thanks :) Also How do I create a Certificate object as I don't have a certificate file either ?

P.S. My RSA keys are generated as shown for both sides

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey pvtKey = kp.getPrivate();
PublicKey pubKey = kp.getPublic();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is BouncyCastle cryptography library's [example](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/misc/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/examples/PKCS12Example.java), how to create different certificates in Java. If you don't have any other key pair as mentioned, you will be able to produce only self-signed certificates.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible without Bouncy Castle though, my problem is how do I generate a Certificate object using an InputStream using this method "generateCertificate(InputStream inStream)" from CertificateFactory when I don't have a Certificate file in the first place to make an InputStream with ?

Comment: This is easy. You have to generate a certificate using BouncyCastle as described, save it to a file, open the file with `FileInputStream` and pass it to `CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(InputStream)`.